# Neo4j Design: When to use Properties for Relationships

Tags: database-design, neo4j

**What is the proper case for using the [Property](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-relationships.html#rest-api-create-a-relationship-with-properties) attribute of a [Relationship](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-relationships.html) in [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/)?** *(Including examples of when and when not to use them)*

---

#### Example

Consider a computer used by `Team A` and `Team B`, where each team have their own internal value `id` for the computer:

```
Node = Team : properties = {'name'='Team A'}
^
|
Relationship = "Used By..."
|
Node = Computer : properties = {'Type':'MacBook', 'CPU':'i7', 'id'='TeamA1-MBKi7'}
```

If `Team B` has the same relationship but with a different value for `id`:

Would it be correct to move the property `id` out of the `Computer` node and into a relationship property?

e.g.

```
Node = Team : properties = {'name'='Team A'}
^
|
Relationship = "Used By..." : properties = {'id'='TeamA1-MBKi7'}
|
Node = Computer : properties = {'Type':'MacBook', 'CPU':'i7'}
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways that you *could* model this.  But to answer how you *should*, can you tell us more about what this ID is supposed to mean?   OK, so a team uses a particular computer.  Possibly other teams use the same computer.  What does `TeamA1-MBKi7` mean?

Comment: `TeamA1-MBKi7` would just be a unique reference used within each `Team` to refer to their usage of a particular `Computer`. The example is just a hypothetical one, the question is actually about when and why you may use a property field in a relationship. The example just serves as a theoretical case to provoke discussion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To address your specific example, you could add a new `Model` node label to describe a type of computer, as in:

```
(:Team {name: 'Team A'})<-[:USED_BY]-(:Computer {id: 'TeamA1-MBKi7'})-[:IS_A]->(:Model {type:'MacBook', cpu:'i7'})
```

That will allow multiple `Computer` nodes to share the same model information.

To address your more general question, here are some thoughts:

1. Neo4j currently does not allow you to create an index or uniqueness constraint on a relationship. (Remember, for nodes: an index or uniqueness constraint is always associated with a node label AND a node property.) Therefore, if you wanted to (or might want to) create an index or a uniqueness constraint involving a property, you should put it in a node.
2. A relationship can only be used once, to make a single connection between 2 nodes. If you wanted to (or might ever want to) involve the same property value in multiple connections, you should consider putting it in a node.
3. If a property is always relevant to a specific pair of nodes (and is not relevant to just one of those nodes), then it should be a relationship property.

Comment: The question is really aimed at when and when not to use properties in relationships. I am trying to ascertain why you did not want to use a property within the relationship to describe the data